# How to apply styles to an element inside div ? i have some content inside <div>, i want to move that to left

Tags: html, css

I have below content in my HTML, i want to move it to left 100px, could someone please help me to do that.

```
<div>This is some test data for which styles should be applied..</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Have you done at least *any* research? In other words, have you studied css?

Answer (score 1):

In the **CSS**, there is a **classes** and **id's**.
Classes are needed for **combining some elements**:

```
<h1 class="test">Lorem Ipsum</h1>
```

And in CSS:

```
h1.test {
margin-right:100px;
}
```

ID's you can assign **only one element**:

```
<h1 id="test">Lorem Ipsum</h1>
```

And in CSS:

```
h1#test {
margin-right:100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

html:

```
<div class="test">This is some test data for which styles should be applied</div>
```

CSS:

```
.test{
    position: absolute;
    left: -100px;
}
```

This will move the div off screen to the left by 100px, or to the left of the next parent element that has `position: relative`.

Comment: Can you please add some explanation?